# File organization: aesthetics and security

Tags: php, html

I'm building my first relatively large website, and the files are getting to the point where I really should be organizing more so I don't get lost. So I was wondering if there were any benefits to putting php and html files into different folders as opposed to leaving them all in one folder and organizing them by names, possibly with folders to break them up(like put folder "b" in to separate a.php and b.html when viewing). So I have two specific questions about file organization:

Would leaving all of the files in one folder propose any security risks?

Does separating the files into a bunch of different folders slow down the speed any measurable amount?

Are there any other quantifiable differences, other than aesthetics?

Answer (score 1):

It is generally **good practice** to organize your files into folders like, allotting specific folders for PHP, JS, CSS, Images, HTML etc. This helps you keep things neat and clean when your large web application is scaling upwards. AFAIK, there is no performance gain in doing this. However, there might be some security aspects, like, imagine one folder gets hacked and you're whole application sits there. It's compromised.

Separating out different files in different folders just reduces this probability. But again, it'd be stupid so say file organization is a important metric for website security, as there are loads of other things you should be caring about, within the code, like **refactoring**, **well engineered software** and **database optimization** for performance and security gain.

Note that if you happen to use a MVC PHP framework like Codeigniter, Symphony, Kohana, Zend etc, you will be inclined to do this type of file organization anyway, in terms of separating different layers into folders like, **model, view and controller**. I would recommend you look at the various options with great care and do not hesitate to ask more questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I usually leave the index.php file alone and put all other files in folders. I will have a folder for CSS, one for JS, one for PHP classes associated with the DB, one for the PHP scripts, one for image files, etc.

The most important thing about security is to make sure your .htaccess files are well configured.

Answer (score 0):

[Zeelot's "project template"](https://github.com/Zeelot/kohana-projecttemplate) serves two purposes. It's an example of a well structured project, but it's also designed to be a template to get you started with your own project. A lot of best practices are baked into it. Kohana is a brilliant framework, but even if you decide not to use it there is still plenty to learn from this.